# Configuring GAC-placed assemblies. Best practice

Tags: .net, configuration, assemblies, gac

I have to implement .net assembly that would be put into GAC. It relies on RDBMS connection string and some additional params - what is the best place I should put it? Machine.config, registry or something more appropriate?

Such information should be placed into application configuration file (app.config/web.config) that uses component (as noticed Marek Grzenkowicz), but what if application config is untouchable for some reasons?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Voting to close: You ask a question with as the main piece of information that the normal (best) solution can't be used, without any further information or requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to license an application developed in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331314/how-to-license-an-application-developed-in-c)

Comment: yeah, it's abnormal situation.

Comment: There might be a serious question in here but then you hid it well. How can machine.config be an option when app.config isn't? Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put such information into `app.config` / `web.config` file of application that uses the assembly. This way it will be possible to specify different settings for each such application.

Comment: Yes, thats true. I forgot to mention that app config is not editable for some reasons :(

Comment: @Andrew Florko: Add this information to the original question and explain exactly what you mean by *app.config is not editable*. Is that a requirement? Don't you have appropriate permissions? Does the `app.config` file belong to some 3rd party application?

Comment: This is a component for application we have no administration access to change config. I should contact administrators & ask to make some changes for us - may be it would be better to change their valuable application config then to ask them to change machine.config or run registry modification script.

Answer (score 2):

I would think it would depend on how involved you want dependent assemblies to be in managing the settings.

A set-once-don't-think-about-it-anymore approach could be satisfied very well by the registry. A disadvantage of using the registry is lack of built-in support for retrieving the connection string in ADO.NET classes.

A this-might-be-different-on-a-per-application-basis approach might be satisfied better by demanding settings be in the application's app.config or web.config. The config files offer the added benefit of builtin connection string support for many ADO.NET-related classes.

I'm always a little leery of modifying the machine.config. I cannot explain why, really, except that the setting is global. Every connection string name used in a machine.config is a name that propagates to other configs and must either be used, ignored, or removed. It also complicates syncing development environments with production. That said, I do not suppose these reasons are super-compelling reasons to avoid the machine.config. Just weigh the tradeoffs before making a decision.

Custom files in isolated storage is another viable option, though it is typically used in limited trust environments; since the GAC is full trust, isolated storage may not be as compelling an option.

Answer (score 1):

A 'component' that uses a specific database probably should not be in the GAC in the first place.

If you really need this, the Connectionstring is not a configuration in the normal sense. You should probably hard-code it into your assembly.

And please remind me never to install your software.

Comment: Nice comment! :) Application I write for uses GAC installed components as external plugins that fully specified by [assembly + class name] described in registry(!).